# How to capture STDOUT from Perl open pipe?

Tags: perl, wget

How would I capture the STDOUT return from wget being called by Perl in the following way and put it into a variable?

```
my @urls = ('url1', 'url2', 'url3');

open(GET, "| xargs -n1 -P 3 wget -qO- ") || die "get failed: $!\n";
print GET "@urls";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to slurp all the data at once, [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aRun) can do that.

```
use IPC::Run qw(run);
run [qw(xargs -n1 -P 3 wget -qO-)], \"@urls", \my $out;
print "$out";
```

If you want to process data as it is made available, [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aRun) can do that too.

```
use IPC::Run qw(run);
run [qw(xargs -n1 -P 3 wget -qO-)], \"@urls", sub {
    print $_[0];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [your pipe is an input pipe, and `open` doesn't support both input and output pipes](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html). As an alternative, use a piped output and open one file handle per URL:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @urls=qw(url1 url2 url3);

foreach my $url(@urls)
{
  open(my $get,"-|","wget $url") or die $!;

  print while(<$get>);

  close($get);
}
```

Comment: Hooray...yet more serial downvoting.